# DB update notifier for separate applications that share the same DB

Tags: java, database, hibernate, events, ipc

Say I have two standalone Java applications A and B sharing the same Hibernate DB in the same OS.  If A updates the DB I'd like B to be notified as well (so it can refresh its cached data etc.), and vice versa. What would be the best/simplest approach to solve this problem?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: few databases (Microsoft AFAIK) have nonportable event system, probably not implemented in JDBC. But maybe in Java application better is JMS or equivalent?

Comment: Are you saying they share the same physical database but the two applications use different tables and you need to simply replicate the changes from one table to another?

Comment: Naros, they share the same database (schema and data).  Both applications can write to the same DB and each JVM has its own cache of the data.  So if one application changes the DB, I need a way to let the other application aware and sync its cache.